# Export Animations to Wikitude

Tags: animation, export, nla-editor

I am trying to export a scene to Wikitude 3D Encoder. The scene is nothing special, for now a simple cube will do. However, I would like to have multiple animations available for this object which I can then later on trigger in Wikitude.

I found that using the NLA Editor will give me multiple animations in the FBX file, and they also import into Wikitude. However, only the last animation is used, no matter which one I trigger.

To be clear: I define a separate action for Move, Rotate and Scale cube. I create an NLA track for each. I export to FBX and import into Wikitude. I do see three animations there, but no matter which one I click, I only see one of them executed. It is the one at the bottom in the NLA editor, in this example the scaling. So when I execute 'Scale' it scales, when I execute 'Rotate' it scales, when I click 'Move' it scales. Hope this is somewhat understandable...

Any ideas?